# SQL Server datetime sorting

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to sort a `datetime` object in SQL Server between two dates. When I run it, it has filtered down the results but not properly.

My code is

```
where 
    cast(tbRegistrant.DateEntered as date) >= cast('2015-07-01' as date) 
    and tbRegistrant.DateEntered <= cast('2016-06-30' as date)
```

The results coming back would be

```
2008-08-06 14:14:55.000
2015-06-09 10:18:02.000
2014-11-25 14:18:24.000
2014-11-24 14:11:23.000
2014-11-24 14:06:14.000
2015-01-30 13:41:25.000
2008-08-06 13:23:58.000
2014-06-19 12:22:27.000
2014-11-25 15:30:15.000
2014-11-25 08:13:52.000
2014-11-24 14:12:55.000
2015-07-13 08:20:28.000
```

Comment: When you say "sort" do you mean "filter"? Also what does "not properly" mean?

Comment: What results do you get? In what way are they not being sorted "properly"? Please post your raw data and your sorted results.

Comment: yes filter and returns random dates and not dates between the two specified dates

Comment: Please post your raw data and the results of your query.

Comment: are you definitely displaying tbRegistrant.DateEntered, not some other date field or schema, e.g. dbo.DateEntered ?

Comment: all I can think of is there is some strangeness in your regional date settings and you could try an iso date format, cast('20150701' as date) , what does SELECT cast('2015-07-01' as date)  give you?

Comment: The column in the database was misspelled which was the reason it wasn't working. Got it working now. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your second condition **doesnt** include `CAST`. Should be:

```
where cast(tbRegistrant.DateEntered as date) >= cast('2015-07-01' as date) 
  and cast(tbRegistrant.DateEntered as date) <= cast('2016-06-30' as date);
```

OR

```
where cast(tbRegistrant.DateEntered as date) 
      BETWEEN cast('2015-07-01' as date) and cast('2016-06-30' as date);
```

But better yet, save your date as `DATE` not `TEXT`. right now you cant use any index for your search.

**EDIT:**

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/PMNVS13756)** with OP "wrong" data query bring correct filter. So maybe there is something else.

[image]

And if your field is `datetime` you dont need `CAST`.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
where [DateEntered] >= cast('2015-07-01' as date) 
  and [DateEntered] <= cast('2016-06-30' as date);
```

Comment: they are saved as datetime in the database.. and that syntax doesn't work.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "that syntax doesn't work" ? do you get an error and if yes, which?

Comment: @DennisOakdale what errer are you getting? CAST works for 2008 and onward.

Comment: Not getting an error. Just returns the wrong data. I get returned the above results and not results between the two dates

Comment: Sql server will implicitly cast `'2016-06-30'` to `datetime`.

Comment: @DennisOakdale please post your entire query in the original post. It's not your where clause that is causing the issue i don't think. what you posted shouldn't return that so there must be an error elsewhere

Comment: are you definitely SELECTING the field in your WHERE clause, I notice it has a schema tbRegistrant for example

Comment: select * from tbRegistrant where cast(tbRegistrant.DateEntered as date) >= cast('2015-07-01' as date) 
  and cast(tbRegistrant.DateEntered as date)<= cast('2016-06-30' as date)    Thats the entire query. I don't think it is something else causing it not to work. and dateEntered is in the database as a datetime variable

Comment: @DennisOakdale Check the DEMO I add. Using your wrong result I get the correct filter. Maybe you have something else.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
where cast(tbRegistrant.DateEntered as date) >= cast('20150701' as date) 
  and CAST(tbRegistrant.DateEntered) <= cast('20160630' as date)
```